# Spring bean Log4j autowiring return null

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, autowired

I am trying to create a bean to have the logger object ready as follows:

```
@Bean
public Logger createLogger() {
    return Logger.getLogger("customLog");
}
```

And use it using @Autowired:

```
@Autowired
Logger log;
```

But it doesn't work, the log object is always null.
What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the getLogger() returns something that is not null?

Comment: Are you sure the Autowired Logger is not from another package (logback, java.util...) ?

Comment: It's from 'org.apache.log4j'. 
When I do the same using static call like: private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("customLog"); it works fine... so I think that getLogger("customLog") is not returning null and the problem is with spring autowiring.